# How can I create string out of specific amount of bytes from istream?

Tags: c++, string, istream

I need to create a std::string with first N bytes of istream... How do I do that?

```
std::istream istm;

std::string  str;
istm >> str;              //will read tons of stuff until finds whitespace

std::string  str(N, ' ');
istm.read(str.data(), N); //can't write into buffer inside string, cause data() returns const char*

std::unique_ptr<char[N+1]> buf;
istm.read(buf.get(), N);
std::string str(buf.get());                //should work, but why extra buffer?
```

so... how do I do that a good way?

Comment: Why not just read one byte at a time, perhaps with a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

There's a non-`const` `data()` since C++17.

Before then, you can pass `&str[0]` instead, which gives you the same thing.

Note that this was technically unsafe until C++11, as C++98/03 did not explicitly guarantee contiguous storage for string data (though this was generally the case in practice for a number of reasons).